# On running adminlogin test - File or path C not found Exception occuring

Tags: magento2.3.5-p1

I have installed the magento at my local end through xampp. Then first test i executed that is 'AdminLoginTest'. Used the command - mftf run:test AdminLoginTest to execute the test.
I followed the link : https://devdocs.magento.com/mftf/docs/getting-started.html#wysiwyg-settings for installation and building the project.
Here is the logs on console:

```
 ! [NOTE] MFTF NOTICES:
    DEPRECATED ACTIONS: "executeInSelenium" and "performOn" actions will be removed in MFTF
     !        3.0.0
    DEPRECATED TEST PATH: support for "dev/tests/acceptance/tests/functional/Magento/FunctionalTest will be
     !        removed in MFTF 3.0.0
    XSD schema change to only allow single entity per xml file for all entities except data
     !        and metadata in MFTF 3.0.0
    DEPRECATION: Test AdminScheduledImportSettingsHiddenTest is missing required annotations.{"testName":"AdminScheduledImportSettingsHiddenTest","missingAnnotations":"stories"}
    DEPRECATION: Test AdminChangeAllCustomersGroupViaGridTest is missing required annotations.{"testName":"AdminChangeAllCustomersGroupViaGridTest","missingAnnotations":"stories, severity"}
    DEPRECATION: Test StorefrontUpdateCustomerPasswordRedirectOnLoginPage is missing required annotations.{"testName":"StorefrontUpdateCustomerPasswordRedirectOnLoginPage","missingAnnotations":"stories, severity"}
    DEPRECATION: Test NoErrorForMiniCartItemEditTest is missing required annotations.{"testName":"NoErrorForMiniCartItemEditTest","missingAnnotations":"stories"}
    DEPRECATION: Test AdminUpdateCmsPageRewriteEntityWithNoRedirectTest is missing required annotations.{"testName":"AdminUpdateCmsPageRewriteEntityWithNoRedirectTest","missingAnnotations":"severity"}
    DEPRECATION: Test AdminUpdateCmsPageRewriteEntityWithPermanentRedirectTest is missing required annotations.{"testName":"AdminUpdateCmsPageRewriteEntityWithPermanentRedirectTest","missingAnnotations":"severity"}
    DEPRECATION: Test AdminUpdateCmsPageRewriteEntityWithTemporaryRedirectTest is missing required annotations.{"testName":"AdminUpdateCmsPageRewriteEntityWithTemporaryRedirectTest","missingAnnotations":"severity"}
    DEPRECATION: Test AdminDeleteIntegrationEntityTest is missing required annotations.{"testName":"AdminDeleteIntegrationEntityTest","missingAnnotations":"severity"}
    DEPRECATION: Test AdminCardinalCommerceSettingsHiddenTest is missing required annotations.{"testName":"AdminCardinalCommerceSettingsHiddenTest","missingAnnotations":"stories"}
    DEPRECATION: Test AdminCreateSimpleProductReassignSource is missing required annotations.{"testName":"AdminCreateSimpleProductReassignSource","missingAnnotations":"severity"}
    DEPRECATION: Test AdminUserCreatedShipmentForWholeOrderWithSimpleProductFromTestSourceWithNumericSourceCodeTest is missing required annotations.{"testName":"AdminUserCreatedShipmentForWholeOrderWithSimpleProductFromTestSourceWithNumericSourceCodeTest","missingAnnotations":"stories"}
    DEPRECATION: Test LoggedInCustomerOrderedGroupedProductWithChildProductsAssignedToDefaultStockFromHomepageTest is missing required annotations.{"testName":"LoggedInCustomerOrderedGroupedProductWithChildProductsAssignedToDefaultStockFromHomepageTest","missingAnnotations":"description"}
    DEPRECATION: Test VerifyThatMessageOnlyZeroLeftNotAppearedOnSimpleProductPageOnFrontendTest is missing required annotations.{"testName":"VerifyThatMessageOnlyZeroLeftNotAppearedOnSimpleProductPageOnFrontendTest","missingAnnotations":"severity"}
    DEPRECATION: Test VerifyThatMessageOnlyZeroLeftNotAppearedOnSimpleProductPageOnFrontendWithMainWebsiteAssignedAsSalesChannelTest is missing required annotations.{"testName":"VerifyThatMessageOnlyZeroLeftNotAppearedOnSimpleProductPageOnFrontendWithMainWebsiteAssignedAsSalesChannelTest","missingAnnotations":"stories, title, severity"}
    DEPRECATION: Test VerifyThatMessageOnlyZeroLeftNotAppearedOnSimpleProductPageOnFrontendWithWebsiteAndNewStoreAndNewStoreViewTest is missing required annotations.{"testName":"VerifyThatMessageOnlyZeroLeftNotAppearedOnSimpleProductPageOnFrontendWithWebsiteAndNewStoreAndNewStoreViewTest","missingAnnotations":"stories, title, severity"}
    DEPRECATION: Test VerifyThatMessageOnlyZeroLeftNotAppearedOnSimpleProductPageOnFrontendWithoutTestWebsiteAssignedAsSalesChannelTest is missing required annotations.{"testName":"VerifyThatMessageOnlyZeroLeftNotAppearedOnSimpleProductPageOnFrontendWithoutTestWebsiteAssignedAsSalesChannelTest","missingAnnotations":"stories, title, severity"}
    DEPRECATION: Test AddBundleDynamicFromCustomStockBySkuFromCustomerAccountTest is missing required annotations.{"testName":"AddBundleDynamicFromCustomStockBySkuFromCustomerAccountTest","missingAnnotations":"stories, title, severity"}
    DEPRECATION: Test AddConfigurableFromCustomStockBySkuFromCustomerAccountTest is missing required annotations.{"testName":"AddConfigurableFromCustomStockBySkuFromCustomerAccountTest","missingAnnotations":"stories, title, severity"}
    DEPRECATION: Test AddSimpleFromCustomStockBySkuFromCustomerAccountTest is missing required annotations.{"testName":"AddSimpleFromCustomStockBySkuFromCustomerAccountTest","missingAnnotations":"stories, title, severity"}
    DEPRECATION: Test AddSimpleOutOfStockFromCustomStockBySkuFromCustomerAccountTest is missing required annotations.{"testName":"AddSimpleOutOfStockFromCustomStockBySkuFromCustomerAccountTest","missingAnnotations":"description, severity"}
    DEPRECATION: Test CreateOrderWithConfigurableProductCustomStockCustomWebsiteBySkuFromCustomerAccountTest is missing required annotations.{"testName":"CreateOrderWithConfigurableProductCustomStockCustomWebsiteBySkuFromCustomerAccountTest","missingAnnotations":"stories, title, severity"}
    DEPRECATION: Test StoreFrontQTYChangeCustomStockProductVariationOfConfigurableProductTest is missing required annotations.{"testName":"StoreFrontQTYChangeCustomStockProductVariationOfConfigurableProductTest","missingAnnotations":"stories, title, severity"}
    DEPRECATION: Test StorefrontAddCustomStockProductWithFileToTheCartFromRequisitionListTest is missing required annotations.{"testName":"StorefrontAddCustomStockProductWithFileToTheCartFromRequisitionListTest","missingAnnotations":"stories, title, severity"}
    DEPRECATION: Test AdminSignifydConfigDependentOnActiveFieldTest is missing required annotations.{"testName":"AdminSignifydConfigDependentOnActiveFieldTest","missingAnnotations":"stories"}
    DEPRECATION: Test AdminSetUpWatermarkForSwatchImageTest is missing required annotations.{"testName":"AdminSetUpWatermarkForSwatchImageTest","missingAnnotations":"stories"}
    DEPRECATION: Test VertexAsRegisteredCustomerFromStorefrontWithBillToAndShipToTheSameCheckDigitalProductVertexTaxJournalOnInvoice is missing required annotations.{"testName":"VertexAsRegisteredCustomerFromStorefrontWithBillToAndShipToTheSameCheckDigitalProductVertexTaxJournalOnInvoice","missingAnnotations":"severity"}
    DEPRECATION: Test VertexAsRegisteredCustomerFromStorefrontWithBillToAndShipToTheSameCheckDigitalProductVertexTaxJournalOnOrderStatusChange is missing required annotations.{"testName":"VertexAsRegisteredCustomerFromStorefrontWithBillToAndShipToTheSameCheckDigitalProductVertexTaxJournalOnOrderStatusChange","missingAnnotations":"severity"}
    DEPRECATION: Test VertexAsRegisteredCustomerFromStorefrontWithBillToAndShipToTheSameCheckDigitalProductVertexTaxJournalOnCreditMemo is missing required annotations.{"testName":"VertexAsRegisteredCustomerFromStorefrontWithBillToAndShipToTheSameCheckDigitalProductVertexTaxJournalOnCreditMemo","missingAnnotations":"severity"}
    DEPRECATION: Test VertexAsRegisteredCustomerFromStorefrontWithBillToAndShipToTheSameForOrderStatusChangeCheckDigitalProductVertexTaxJournalOnCreditMemo is missing required annotations.{"testName":"VertexAsRegisteredCustomerFromStorefrontWithBillToAndShipToTheSameForOrderStatusChangeCheckDigitalProductVertexTaxJournalOnCreditMemo","missingAnnotations":"severity"}
    DEPRECATION: Test VertexAsRegisteredCustomerFromStorefrontWithBillToAndShipToTheSameCheckPhysicalProductVertexTaxJournalOnInvoice is missing required annotations.{"testName":"VertexAsRegisteredCustomerFromStorefrontWithBillToAndShipToTheSameCheckPhysicalProductVertexTaxJournalOnInvoice","missingAnnotations":"severity"}
    DEPRECATION: Test VertexAsRegisteredCustomerFromStorefrontWithBillToAndShipToTheSameCheckPhysicalProductVertexTaxJournalOnCreditMemo is missing required annotations.{"testName":"VertexAsRegisteredCustomerFromStorefrontWithBillToAndShipToTheSameCheckPhysicalProductVertexTaxJournalOnCreditMemo","missingAnnotations":"severity"}

     ! [NOTE] MFTF NOTICES:
    DEPRECATED ACTIONS: "executeInSelenium" and "performOn" actions will be removed in MFTF
     !        3.0.0
    DEPRECATED TEST PATH: support for "dev/tests/acceptance/tests/functional/Magento/FunctionalTest will be
     !        removed in MFTF 3.0.0
    XSD schema change to only allow single entity per xml file for all entities except data
     !        and metadata in MFTF 3.0.0
```

`

> ```
> Generate Tests Command Run
> Codeception PHP Testing Framework v2.4.5
> Powered by PHPUnit 6.5.14 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
>
> Warning: Use of undefined constant LC_MESSAGES - assumed 'LC_MESSAGES' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in
> ```
>
> C:\xampp\htdocs\updatedMagento-ce-2.3.5-p1_sample_data-2020-04-24-10-19-21\vendor\codeception\codeception\src\Codeception\Lib\Di.php on line 84
>       PHP Warning:  Use of undefined constant LC_MESSAGES - assumed 'LC_MESSAGES' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\updatedMagento-ce-2.3.5-p1_sample_data-2020-04-24-10-19-21\vendor\codeception\codeception\src\Codeception\Lib\Di.php on line 84
>
> ```
> In Loader.php line 96:
>
>   [Exception]
>   File or path C not found
> ```

```
Exception trace:
  at C:\xampp\htdocs\updatedMagento-ce-2.3.5-p1_sample_data-2020-04-24-10-19-21\vendor\codeception\codeception\src\Codeception\Test\Loader.php:96
 Codeception\Test\Loader->makePath() at C:\xampp\htdocs\updatedMagento-ce-2.3.5-p1_sample_data-2020-04-24-10-19-21\vendor\codeception\codeception\src\Codeception\Test\Loader.php:104
 Codeception\Test\Loader->loadTest() at C:\xampp\htdocs\updatedMagento-ce-2.3.5-p1_sample_data-2020-04-24-10-19-21\vendor\codeception\codeception\src\Codeception\Test\Loader.php:128
 Codeception\Test\Loader->loadTests() at C:\xampp\htdocs\updatedMagento-ce-2.3.5-p1_sample_data-2020-04-24-10-19-21\vendor\codeception\codeception\src\Codeception\SuiteManager.php:95
 Codeception\SuiteManager->loadTests() at C:\xampp\htdocs\updatedMagento-ce-2.3.5-p1_sample_data-2020-04-24-10-19-21\vendor\codeception\codeception\src\Codeception\Codecept.php:188
 Codeception\Codecept->runSuite() at C:\xampp\htdocs\updatedMagento-ce-2.3.5-p1_sample_data-2020-04-24-10-19-21\vendor\codeception\codeception\src\Codeception\Codecept.php:158
 Codeception\Codecept->run() at C:\xampp\htdocs\updatedMagento-ce-2.3.5-p1_sample_data-2020-04-24-10-19-21\vendor\codeception\codeception\src\Codeception\Command\Run.php:355
 Codeception\Command\Run->execute() at C:\xampp\htdocs\updatedMagento-ce-2.3.5-p1_sample_data-2020-04-24-10-19-21\vendor\symfony\console\Command\Command.php:255
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at C:\xampp\htdocs\updatedMagento-ce-2.3.5-p1_sample_data-2020-04-24-10-19-21\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php:1001
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at C:\xampp\htdocs\updatedMagento-ce-2.3.5-p1_sample_data-2020-04-24-10-19-21\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php:271
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at C:\xampp\htdocs\updatedMagento-ce-2.3.5-p1_sample_data-2020-04-24-10-19-21\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php:147
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at C:\xampp\htdocs\updatedMagento-ce-2.3.5-p1_sample_data-2020-04-24-10-19-21\vendor\codeception\codeception\src\Codeception\Application.php:108
 Codeception\Application->run() at C:\xampp\htdocs\updatedMagento-ce-2.3.5-p1_sample_data-2020-04-24-10-19-21\vendor\codeception\codeception\codecept:42



run [-o|--override OVERRIDE] [-e|--ext EXT] [--report] [--html [HTML]] [--xml [XML]] [--tap [TAP]] [--json [JSON]] [--colors] [--no-colors] [--silent] [--steps] [-d|--debug] [--coverage [COVERAGE]] [--coverage-html [COVERAGE-HTML]] [--coverage-xml [COVERAGE-XML]] [--coverage-text [COVERAGE-TEXT]] [--coverage-crap4j [COVERAGE-CRAP4J]] [--coverage-phpunit [COVERAGE-PHPUNIT]] [--no-exit] [-g|--group GROUP] [-s|--skip SKIP] [-x|--skip-group SKIP-GROUP] [--env ENV] [-f|--fail-fast] [--no-rebuild] [--] [<suite> [<test>]]
```

Few more observations on the issue:
1. Loader file is not getting correct test file path.
2. I installed open source edition and after installing as per the instructions in devdocs of magento i ran the command mftf run:test AdminLoginTest in /vendor/bin so it gave the error mftf command unrecoginzable then i put the windowsBatchFile of mftf in the folder that i copied from the code of magento which i cloned from the git. So is it the reason for the issue?

Any help would be appreciable.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get past it by commenting out vendor/codeception/codeception/src/Codeception/Command/Run.php:348: `$filter = $this->matchFilteredTestName($test);`

It's probably a windows error, it explodes on ':', so C:/xampp/... will cause the wrong separation. A probable better way is to pass a test argument to the command, see `$test = $input->getArgument('test');`

Comment: Thanks for the response, i will try it again and accordingly update the same, however i have switched on linux and it's working on that.